# JS FadeIn not working on "a href"

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

Using JS function FadeIn in very basic document, it is not working.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="h1">Something</h1>
        <div class="btn" id="btn">  
            <a href="main.html">ENTER</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var main = function() {
            //$('#h1').fadeIn(3200);
            $('#btn').fadeIn(1000);
        };

        $(document).ready(main);
    </script>
</body>
```

The first "h1" element works as it should, however the "btn" doesn´t respond at all. Can it be maybe in CSS?

**CSS**

```
btn a {
  display: none;
  background: #00cccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 44%;
}

.btn a:hover { 
 background: #00a58f;
}
```

Comment: With CSS, you're hiding the `<a>` *inside* the button. Then, with jQuery, you're fading in the button itself.

Comment: Why are you loading two different versions of jQuery?

Comment: And why do you use `<a>` for buttons when there is great support for the native `<button>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `CSS` selector is looking for a tag called `btn`

Use a class selector instead

`.btn a {`

Also you would need to fadeId the `a` element instead as that is the one that is hidden.

```
$('#btn a').fadeIn(1000);
```

If you are instead fading the div, set display none to the `div` itself.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ns7eh050/)**

Comment: adding the "a" after .btn did the trick for me, it escaped me that I need to use the whole thing. (The CSS selector was in original code, I just made mistkae copying it). Also the ".fadeOut" method is an interesting solution as suggested by @Slatin Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

change your css to target the correct `#btn div`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
#btn {
  display: none;
  background: #00cccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 44%;
}


.btn a:hover { 
 background: #00a58f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "container">
    <h1 id="h1">Something</h1>
    <div class="btn" id="btn">
        <a href="main.html">ENTER</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot adding the class selector tp `.btn a` in your css plus you used id in your jquery while you should use class here is fixed code:

```
.btn a {
  display: none;
  background: #00cccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 44%;
}

.btn a:hover { 
 background: #00a58f;
}

    <body>
<div class = "container">
    <h1 id="h1">Something</h1>
    <div class="btn" id="btn">
        <a href="main.html">ENTER</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var main = function() {
    //$('#h1').fadeIn(3200);
    $('.btn').fadeIn(1000);
};

$(document).ready(main);

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a half solution? Use JQuery to make both states

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XfR8F2suDnLaySZuQZd1?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

The div needs to start out as hidden. either do a display:none or add this before your fade

$('#btn').hide();